# What is the difference between Reader and InputStream?

Tags: java, file, inputstream, filereader, fileinputstream

What is the difference between Reader and InputStream?
And when to use what?
If I can use Reader for reading characters why I will use inputstream, I guess to read objects?

Comment: Regarding "I guess to read objects?", there are special Input/Output streams for reading/writing Java objects.  They are ObjectInputStream and ObjectOutputStream respectively, and are part of the larger serialization framework.  http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/serialization/  But that's only one use of input/output streams, others could be sending data over a socket, etc.

Answer (score 156, accepted):

An InputStream is the raw method of getting information from a resource.  It grabs the data byte by byte without performing any kind of translation.  If you are reading image data, or any binary file, this is the stream to use.

A Reader is designed for character streams.  If the information you are reading is all text, then the Reader will take care of the character decoding for you and give you unicode characters from the raw input stream.  If you are reading any type of text, this is the stream to use.

You can wrap an InputStream and turn it into a Reader by using the InputStreamReader class.

```
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Comment: flawless answer Berin! Thanks!

Comment: why don't you just use new FileReader(file)?

Comment: @engine, of course you can.  I was demonstrating how to turn _any_ `InputStream` into a `Reader`.  The approach works for socket streams, file streams, classloader streams, etc.  I wasn't trying to imply that it is the only way to get a reader.

Comment: @BerinLoritsch Sorry for missunderstanding

Answer (score 21):

InputStreams are used to read bytes from a stream. So they are useful for binary data such as images, video and serialized objects.

Readers on the other hand are character streams so they are best used to read character data.

Answer (score 18):

I guess the source of confusion is that [`InputStream.read()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read()) returns an `int` and [`Reader.read()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html#read()) also returns an `int`.

The difference is that `InputStream.read()` return byte values between 0 and 255 corresponding to the raw contents of the byte stream and `Reader.read()` return the character value which is between 0 and 65357 (because there are 65358 different unicode codepoints)

An `InputStream` lets you read the contents byte by byte, for example the contents "a‡a" has 3 characters but it's encoded at 5 bytes in UTF-8. So with `Inputstream` you can read it as a stream of 5 bytes (each one represented as an `int` between 0 and 255) resulting in `97`, `226`, `128`, `161` and `97` where

```
a -> U+0061 -> 0x61 (hex) -> 97 (dec)
‡ -> U+2021 -> 0xE280A1 (utf-8 encoding of 0x2021) -> 226 128 161 (1 int per byte)
a -> U+0061 -> 0x61 (hex) -> 97 (dec)
```

A `Reader` lets you read the contents character by character so the contents "a‡a" are read as 3 characters `97`, `8225` and `97` where

```
a -> U+0061 -> 0x61 -> 97
‡ -> U+2021 -> 0x2021 -> 8225 (single int, not 3)
a -> U+0061 -> 0x61 -> 97
```

The character ‡ is referred as [U+2021 in Unicode](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2021/index.htm)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Thank you for the example

Answer (score 2):

One accepts bytes and the other accepts characters.

Answer (score 1):

InputStream accept byte，Reader accept character, In Java, one character = two bytes , and Reader use buffer,InputStream not use. All file store in disk or transfer based on byte, include image and video, but character is in memory,so InputStream is used frequently.