# Trouble reading a file in java in a certain format

Tags: java, file, java.util.scanner

I am reading text from a file and I have been having trouble trying to read `List 1` and `List 2` into 2 different `String` . The `*` indicates where the first list ends. I have tried using arrays but the array only stores the last * symbol.

```
List 1
Name: Greg
Hobby 1: Swimming
Hobby 2: Football
*
List 2
Name: Bob
Hobby 1: Skydiving
*
```

Here's what I tried so far:

```
String s = "";
try{
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("file.txt"));
while(scanner.hasnextLine()){
s = scanner.nextLine();
}
}catch(Exception e){
e.printStackTrace}
String [] array = s.split("*");
String x = array[0];
String y = array[1];
```

Comment: Hint: after the while loop `s` contains just the last line of the file.

Comment: Oh I see, Is there another method I could use to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has multiple issues like @Henry said that your string contains only the last line of the file and also you misunderstood the [`split()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) because it takes a [**Reg**ular**Ex**pression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions) as a parameter.

I would recommend you to use the following example because it works and is a lot faster than your approach.

---

Kick-Off example:

```java
// create a buffered reader that reads from the file
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("test.txt")));

// create a new array to save the lists
ArrayList<String> lists = new ArrayList<>();

String list = ""; // initialize new empty list
String line; // initialize line variable

// read all lines until one becomes null (the end of the file)
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    // checks if the line only contains one *
    if (line.matches("\\s*\\*\\s*")) {
        // add the list to the array of lists
        lists.add(list);
    } else {
        // add the current line to the list
        list += line + "\r\n"; // add the line to the list plus a new line
    }
}
```

#### Explanation

I'm going to explain special lines that are hard to understand again.

---

Looking at the first line:

```java
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("test.txt")));
```

This line creates a [`BufferedReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) that is nearly the same like a `Scanner` but it's a lot faster and hasn't as much methods as a `Scanner`. For this usage the `BufferedReader` is more than enough.

Then it takes an `InputStreamReader` as a parameter in the constructor. This is only to convert the following `FileInputStream` to a `Reader`.

*Why should one do that?* That's because an `InputStream` ≠ `Reader`. An `InputStream` returns the raw values and a `Reader` converts it to human readable characters. See [the difference between `InputStream` and `Reader`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4367539/what-is-the-difference-between-reader-and-inputstream).

---

Looking at the next line:

```java
ArrayList<String> lists = new ArrayList<>();
```

Creates a variable array that has methods like `add()` and `get(index)`. See [the difference of arrays and lists](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/array-vs-arraylist-in-java/).

---

And the last one:

```java
list += line + "\r\n";
```

This line adds the `line` to the current list and adds a new line to it.

`"\r\n"` Are special characters. `\r` ends the current line and `\n` creates a new line.

You could also only use `\n` but adding `\r` in front of it is better because this supports more Os's like Linux can have problems with it when `\r` misses.

---

### Related

[Using BufferedReader to read Text File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16104616/using-bufferedreader-to-read-text-file)

Comment: I see thank you for that. I will need to look into Regular Expressions a bit more before I can implement it into my own code. Would it be possible to stop the buffered reader from reading further from the *(asterisk) and assign the values before it to a String, and the values after it, into a different string?

Comment: @m1759 As far as I understand your question, this is already done. The `ArrayList` contains two values when running the example: one before the asterisk, one after the asterik and if there are more lists, each list will be in an own string. You can access them by `lists.get(0)` and `lists.get(1)`  (this is the same as `array[0]` and `array[1]`). If you've never worked with Lists before, I recommend you to read [this](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_arraylist.asp) article about the `ArrayList`.